# What port is this?

Tags: imac, display, hdmi, television, video-adapter

Questions:

1. Is the display plug in the following picture indeed a Mini-DVI?

[image]

2. Would [this cable](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10419&cs_id=1041912&p_id=4852&seq=1&format=1#largeimage) work? (I would use a regular DVI Male to Male with it)?

Why? My friend wants to connect her Mac (iMac I think) to her TV. I'm thinking I need a Mini-DVI (male) to HDMI (or DVI) and a separate 3.5mm Male to Male for sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is called a MINI-DVI (not Midi as in the first part of your question), but yes it is.

I believe this is a white iMac, these had Mini-DVI (the first Alu iMacs also had Mini-DVI).  This changed just around 2011 with the 2nd Generation of alu iMacs (display port) and the latest generation (Thunderbolt).

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DVI) for details and comparision and see this schematic:

[image]

.

Not sure about that cable from your link though, because to me it looks like a HDMI socket.  However, below is typical monitor (or TV) female DVI input socket:

[image]

.

I would rather expect you to buy [this](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10419&cs_id=1041912&p_id=4851&seq=1&format=1#largeimage) adaptor, which would make the socket similar to any PC video card and then use a normal DVI-DVI cable that would be used to go from a regular DVI video card to the Monitor/TV (I think this is what you mean by "DVI Male to Male").  If your friend's TV has VGA in, there is a VGA version too ([link](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10419&cs_id=1041912&p_id=4850&seq=1&format=1#largeimage)).

Regarding sound, a TV most likely has cinch input for sound (as in the picture above). There are many solutions for 3.5mm-stereo -> cinch (e.g. [this](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10218&cs_id=1021804&p_id=665&seq=1&format=2)).

Comment: Thanks @Nicholaz! I had my friend buy the Mini-DVI to DVI Female, a DVI (male to male) and a 3.5mm to RCA (she'll plug directly in her sound system rather than TV).

Comment: **Important update!** The Mini-DVI to DVI female (see my last comment) did not work. Not sure why. Maybe it has to do with DVI-I vs DVI-D. I'm not sure. What ended up working was the Mini-DVI to VGA (if you don't mind analog vs digital)